# React Redux Reducer triggered but not changing state

Tags: reactjs, redux, reducers

I am trying to set up app state with authenticated: true and user data.
Reducer gets to be triggered (I can see console.log) but it is returning initial state (isAuthenticated: false, user: {})

Thunk is working fine as far as I know

Props I am getting in component is {isAuthenticated: false, user{}}

I have done stuff like this before just like this so I am not sure why is this happening

```js
import { AUTHENTICATED } from '../actions/types'

const initialState = {
    isAuthenticated: false,
    user: {}
}

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case AUTHENTICATED:
            console.log(action.payload)
            return {
                ...state,
                isAuthenticated: true,
                user: action.payload.user
            }

        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

action creator user.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import history from '../history';
import config from '../config'
import { AUTHENTICATED } from './types';

export function authUser(token){
   return function(dispatch){
      const data = {"token": token}
      axios.post(`${config.api_url}/authuser`, data)
         .then((res) => {
            dispatch({type: AUTHENTICATED, payload: res.data})
         })
         .catch((err) => console.log(err))
   }
}
```

component dashboard.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import history from '../history';
import * as actions from '../actions/memberActions';

   class Dashboard extends Component {

      componentWillMount(){
            const token = window.localStorage.getItem('token');
               if(!token){
                  history.push('/')
               }else{
                  this.props.authUser(token);
                  console.log(this.props.user);
         }

      };
      render() {
         return (
            <div>
               <h2>This will be a dashboard page</h2>
               <p>There should be something here:{ this.props.authenticated }</p>
               <h1>OK</h1>

            </div>
         )
      }
   }

function mapStateToProps(state){
   return {
      user: state.user
   }

}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(Dashboard);
```

Comment: To format code, **every** line must begin with 4 extra spaces. You can do this easily by highlighting the code block and pressing Ctrl-K.

Comment: With that said, please [edit] your question to show a [mcve].

Comment: please show  code which you are getting that value.

Comment: Please do a console.log before this line `dispatch({type: AUTHENTICATED, payload: res.data})`. It could be that data is coming blank.

Comment: No console.log in Action Creator comes back nicely with data from API. No problem there

Comment: But it could be that your `res.data` object doesn't have an `user` property. Just post what console log says.

Comment: if possible, please leave a skype id, I can reach out.

Comment: So where are you looking for your changed state? In `dashboard.js`? You're checking `props.user` in `componentWillMount`, which doesn't show your updates. Check the state change in your `render` method, or in another lifecycle handler method like `componentWillReceiveProps`.

Comment: edbreuer1 Eduard Breuer in St. Petersburg FL

Comment: Ahhhh kaveh Thank You Very Much. That was the answer. Can you post this as answer so I can mark it as answered

Comment: @eddbreuer glad it helped. Just copy/pasted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're checking `props.user` in `componentWillMount`, which doesn't show your updates.
Instead check the state change in your `render` method, or in another life-cycle handler method like `componentWillReceiveProps`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be something like this

```
export default function(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case AUTHENTICATED:
            console.log(action.payload)
            return state =  {
                ...state,
                isAuthenticated: true,
                user: action.payload.user
            }

        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see what's different from what OP posted, could you elaborate?

Comment: `return state =  {
                ...state,
                isAuthenticated: true,
                user: action.payload.user
            }` After cloning state, you have to set that value to state

Comment: `import {AUTHENTICATED} from '../actions/types';

const initialState ={
   isAuthenticated: false,
   user: {}
}

export default function(state = initialState , action) {
  switch(action.type) {
     case AUTHENTICATED:
     console.log(action.payload);
     return state = {...state, isAuthenticated: true, user: action.payload.user}

   default: return state;

  }
}`    Still getting initial state

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, seems like your `res.data` object, in `dispatch({type: AUTHENTICATED, payload: res.data})` does not have an `user` property.

So when you do `user: action.payload.user` you're basically saying `user: undefined`.

Please post your `console.log(res.data)` to see if this is the problem.

Comment: {user: {…}, token: "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI1Y…xNzl9.gVpbeGhovcuBtzuxMhDA_xrO8upw6-s5pmH9gVMPJ7U"}
token
:
"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiI1YTk3MDczMDE2OTQ0ZDRhYmM0ZDk0ZDAiLCJpYXQiOjE1MTk5MzA3MTYxNzl9.gVpbeGhovcuBtzuxMhDA_xrO8upw6-s5pmH9gVMPJ7U"
user
:
{_id: "5a97073016944d4abc4d94d0", email: "b225550@nwytg.com", password: "$2a$10$6YAUpy4kqTPApkF.v62zIe7ntE8OSrOLZ4iT4SwPoks9r2e8otYjC", city: "St. Petersburg", zip: "33709", …}
__proto__
:
Object

Comment: So i am getting everything right but reducer is not changing initial state